# Ethernet keystone jack color conventions?

Tags: ethernet, cabling, best-practices

In a similar vein as [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/cable-colors-and-purpose)...

Are there any conventions or standards that recommend a color scheme for the colors of Ethernet keystone jacks?

[image: colored jacks]

Comment: I hope someone answers yes because I'm not aware of one and it would be really cool if there were one.

Comment: There are, but only in specialized environments (i.e. hospital, military, etc.)

Comment: @RickyBeam, do you know the names of any such standards, or can you link to them?

Comment: Sorry. I don't.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I asked for standards or widely practiced conventions. The existing answers only detail personal conventions, and do not give evidence that no relevant standards exist, nor that there are no such conventions.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I am just doing a year-end cleanup of questions with answers where no answers are accepted. Also, "_do not give evidence that no relevant standards exist, nor that there are no such conventions._" remember that it can be impossible to prove a negative.

Comment: @RonMaupin, sure, I even almost said at much myself. But no one's even definitively claimed as much yet. *shrug*

Comment: @RonMaupin feel free to "demote" the question so it doesn't pop up as often, if such is possible.

Comment: That's not really possible. We will always have such questions as there are many where the OP no longer uses SE sites. The first year we did this, we got around 1300 accepted answers from old questions, and the people answering really appreciate getting recognized. I do not really look at the questions and answers, only that there is a question with no accepted answers, and paste in the comment. If you ever find an answer, you are free to come back and answer it and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience is that we use whatever color matches the paint in the room its in, unless it is one of the following:

Red: Hospital Monitoring Equipment
Blue: Security Cameras
Green: Any separate LAN or VLAN connection (ie. radiology has a few of these)

I don't believe there is a specific standard for them.

Correction: as Comments state below talk to your AHJ

Comment: Many times, it may be up to the local Authority Having Jurisdiction. My company had a color scheme which we used everywhere until we ran into inspectors in some cities that each had their own color schemes. Despite any national or international standards, the AHJ always has final say.

Comment: I would assume he is the AHJ in his network if he is the system admin.

Comment: That would be an incorrect assumption which could get someone in a lot of trouble by having an entire building red-tagged as unfit for occupation until the problems are corrected. The local building inspector, fire marshal, etc. would be the AHJ. There are a lot of laws around cabling that need to be met.

Comment: @ronmaupin, can you cite specific instances where an inspector would care about the  jack color?

Comment: @Mike Pennington, for instance, in Plano, TX, red is strictly reserved for lifeline services. I'm not completely sure of the definition, but we were not allowed to use red. There are a few other places in the over 200 cities and towns in the DFW Metroplex that have (or building officials claimed to have) various rules governing color coding of cables and jacks. I have often thought that some of the AHJ officials were just flexing as a show, but what are you going to do?

Comment: OP asked for conventions or standards, not personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard I use across our WAN

We also use a color coding standard for the cables.
- Blue cables for data
- Yellow cables for Voice and phones
- Green for Audio/Video (Televisions, cable boxes, etc.)
- Purple for Wireless access points
- Black for security cameras
- Red is reserved for Fire systems and alarms

Comment: "*Here* is the standard I use across our WAN" - where? Or are you saying you use the same color code for the jacks and the cables?

Comment: Cables, wall jacks and patch panels all have corresponding colors.